# Apache - Deny listing directory but allow access to all subfolders

Tags: apache, directory, directory-structure

How can I deny listing the contents of a parent folder, but allow access to all subfolders?

I.E.

- root (do not list)

  - folder (allow list)

    - a.exe
  - folder (allow list)

    - a.exe
  - folder (allow list)

    - a.exe

Comment: maybe place a `.htaccess` in each subfolder, explicitely allowing access?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Options -Indexes` in htaccess on parent, nothing in childs

Comment: Also needed to edit httpd.conf to "AllowOverride Options", and edit any parent above this. But this worked. Thanks Lazy Badger.

Comment: Not sure about "edit parent above" at all. AllowOverride skipped as obvious req

Comment: Badger, it was set up as '/root/parent/folder'. I had to edit both the .htaccess for root and parent w/ Options -Indexes in order for it to work properly.

Maybe I'm still doing something wrong? It works as I need now, but any clarification would be appreciated. Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Deny Access Directory Listing

```
Options -Indexes
```

Don't have an index in all your directory's? Use this to deny access to all the directory listings, if there is no index file.